# KernelDensity Serialization error in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

Recently I am using KernelDensity class in Spark, I try to Serialize it to my disk in windows10, here is my code:

```
// read sample from disk
val sample = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").csv("D:\\sample")
val trainX = sample.select("_c1").rdd.map(r => r.getDouble(0))

val kd = new KernelDensity().setSample(trainX).setBandwidth(1)
// Serialization
val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("a.obj"))
oos.writeObject(kd)
oos.close()
// deserialization
val ios = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("a.obj"))
val kd1 = ios.readObject.asInstanceOf[KernelDensity]
ios.close()
// error comes when I use estimate
kd1.estimate(Array(1,2, 3))
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$sc(RDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.aggregate(RDD.scala:1117)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity.estimate(KernelDensity.scala:92)
    at KernelDensityConstruction$.main(KernelDensityConstruction.scala:35)
    at KernelDensityConstruction.main(KernelDensityConstruction.scala)
20/05/10 22:05:42 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

why does it not work? if I do not do Serialization operation, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `KernelDensity`, despite being formally `Serializable`, is not designed to be fully compatible with standard serialization tools.

Internally it holds a reference to a sample, which in turn depends on corresponding `SparkContext`. In other words it is distributed tool, which is designed to be used within the scope of a single active session.

Given that:

- It doesn't perform any computations until `estimate` is called.
- It requires sample RDD to evaluate `estimate`.

it doesn't really makes sense to serialize it in the first place ‒ you can simply recreate the object, based on the desired parameters, in the new context.

However, if you really want to serialize the whole thing, you should create a wrapper that serializes both the parameters and the corresponding RDD (in a similar way how ML models with distributed data structures, like ALS, work) and loads these back, within a new session.